# While calling wget from java with consuming the "error" and "output" stream, the sub process tries to run the incomplete command several times

Tags: java, inputstream, wget

I have the following code:

```
public void callWget(String WgetCommand) {
    System.out.println(WgetCommand);
    try {            
       Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
       Process proc = rt.exec(wget_FirstScan);
       int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
       BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
       String line = null;
       while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(line);
       br.close();
       System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
       proc.destroy();
   } catch ( IOException ioe ) { ioe.printStackTrace(); }
     catch ( InterruptedException ie ) { ie.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

The problem is that the subprocess tries to run the incomplete wgetCommand many times and finally it calls the complete command and everything is fine. I believe I have to take care of input stream as well, since the command is long. Is there any body who has any idea on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is that the subprocess tries to run the incomplete wgetCommand many times and finally it calls the complete command and everything is fine.  ... Is there any body who has any idea on this?

I don't know why this would cause the `wget` command to be run more than once.  However, I would definitely not call `proc.waitFor()` until *after* you have finished processing all of the output from the command.  At least under unix, when the process finishes, the underlying input/output/error streams are closed.  Also, if there is a large amount of output, it may fill the OS buffers until you read it, possibly blocking the `wget` from completing causing a deadlock.

So you should do:

```
Process proc = rt.exec(wget_FirstScan);
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
}
br.close();

// wait after processing output
int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
// no need to call proc.destroy()
```

Also, you may want to be processing the `proc.getInputStream();` which is the "standard out" from the wget command.  The `getErrorStream()` is the error messages printed by `wget`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts Gray. I tried your suggested code but unfortunately the same error occurs again. I tried it with shorter wget command and it works fine. I think, there is something wrong with the long command. I also tried consuming the input stream as well, but no success.

Comment: Just as an update, I tried a short command and it works fine.

Comment: By short command I mean something like: "wget http://google.com" and the long command is the one that has several wget parameters and is about one and a half line long.